# Play WAV without delay?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This code plays the WAV three times with a delay between each time.
How can I eliminate this delay?

```
import winsound
for x in range(0, 3):
    winsound.PlaySound(FileName + '.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The winsound module can't do this. You might be able to hack your way to a solution by setting the [loop](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/winsound.html#winsound.SND_LOOP) flag, sleeping for three times the duration, then stopping playback by calling winsound.PlaySound with no arguments, but you would have to make faulty assumptions surrounding the timing of things outside of your control.

How about [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/)?

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
segment = AudioSegment.from_wav(FileName + '.wav')
play(segment * 3)
```